# What value will show like infinity on a textfield?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, textfield

I have this textfield that shows like infinity.

[image]

when I read this value to a variable it shows like `+inf` but suppose I change this textField to another value. What value should I type on the textField to make it infinite again?

This textfield is using a numerical NSFormatter with 2 fractional digits and 1 significant digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user types in something that you want to display as infinity, I'd overwrite - `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` `UITextFieldDelegate` method to return `NO` and did `[myTextField setFloat:+INFINITY]` before that.

Comment: Not exactly, this will help me with another thing, but I was asking about what value should I set the textfield so it will appear infinity. I know that if I do this `[myTextField setFloat:+INFINITY]` it will appear like infinity but I was trying to know if there was something I could type at run time that would make that.

Comment: If I got you right this time, here is what I would do: if the user types in something that you want to display as infinity, I'd overwrite - `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` `UITextFieldDelegate` method to return `NO` and did `[myTextField setFloat:+INFINITY]` before that. Is this it?